# JOIN query with multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In MSSQL with JOIN, it is possible to cross tables from different databases. For example:

```
select 
        PM_ID,
        PR_Name,
        OTD_Name
        from SomeTable
        inner join PRD_Det on PM_ID = PR_Id
        inner join DataBase2.dbo.PRI_Desc on PM_Oper = O_Id
        where PM_Id = @PM_Id
```

I'm trying to make something similar with EntityFramework:

```
        Entities1 _Context1 = new Entities1 ();
        Entities2 _Context2 = new Entities2 ();

        var data = (from w in _Context1 .SomeTable
                    join s in _Context2.PRI_Desc on w.PRD_Det.Single().PM_Oper equals s.O_Id
                    where w.PRD_Det.Single().PM_Id == PM_ID
                    select new SomeDetails()
                        {
                            PM_ID = w.PRD_Det.Single().PM_Id,
                            PR_Name = w.PR_Name,
                            OTD_Name = s.OTD_Name
                        }).ToList();
```

I'm getting the following error

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported in  Entity Framework (as the exception also indicates). You can use `Joins` only on Entities within the same Context.

Comment: I have to make many queries with connection to two databases. After all maybe somebody knows how to use two databases with EF?